# Machine Learning Dataset: Easy enough for fully connected, but not easy enough for logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, logistic-regression

I was wondering if someone could direct me to a dataset for a classification task with the following conditions:

- Multinomial logistic regression alone does not learn a good classifier
- A series of fully connected layers is able to learn a good classifier
- The task is not MNIST

Thank you

Comment: There are lots of datasets you can try but I would simply suggest XOR problem which logistic regression can not perform well on but fully connected layers can achieve a good performance.

Comment: Multinomial logistic can learn almost everything. The point is that you yourself have to find the correct polynomials which is not easy in most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-dimensional problem that should be impossible for logistic regression:

- Generate x uniformly on [0, 10]
- Let y = sin(2 * pi * x)

If you want a classification problem define y_disc as:

- 0 if y > 1/sqrt(2)
- 1 if 1/sqrt(2) > y > -1/sqrt(2)
- 2 if y < -1/sqrt(2).

This is non-linear, so logistic regression should do poorly. Further, if you decide to put higher powers of x into your logistic regression classifier, I think you'll need a lot of powers to accurately represent the Taylor series near 10.

If fact, you could try adding a small noise term to y before discretizing - I suspect that will result in your logistic regressor overfitting long before it's able to accurately approximate the behavior near x=10.